# Use YAML list in a bash script on Azure Pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration

I have a YAML template with parameters that calls another YAML template with a Bash script. I want to use the `tags` YAML array object in the Bash script loop. The goal is to generate multiple tags in the Azure Pipeline from that loop. I tried this:

```
  - stage: TagPipeline
    displayName: Tag Pipeline CI Succeeded
    jobs:
    - job: TagPipeline
      steps:
      - template: /pipeline/blocks/tag-pipeline.yml
        parameters:
          tags:
            - 'Tag1'
            - 'Tag2'
```

`tag-pipeline.yml` is as follows:

```
parameters:
  - name: tags
    displayName: Tags to add to the pipeline
    type: object

steps:
- bash: |
        for tag in ${{ convertToJson(parameters.tags) }};
        do
            "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$tag"
        done
  displayName: Tag Pipeline with $tags
  target: host
```

outcome: ##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.

Comment: And What is the issue?

Comment: ##[error]Bash exited with code '2'.